# Unhandled Runtime Error nextjs - TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'tagName')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

```
  47 | const oldTags = [];
  48 | for(let i = 0, j = headCountEl.previousElementSibling; i < headCount; i++, j = j.previousElementSibling){
> 49 |     if (j.tagName.toLowerCase() === type) {
     |          ^
  50 |         oldTags.push(j);
  51 |     }
  52 | }`
```

Comment: so `j` is null, there is no `previousElementSibling`

Comment: there is a [previousElementSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/previousElementSibling) in js -
@epascarello

Comment: @KavehKarami you misread my comment....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## First Solution

use `j?.tagName.toLowerCase()` instead of `j.tagName.toLowerCase()`

`?.` is the `Optional Chaining` concept in JavaScript

for more information you can check these links:

- [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)
- [JavaScript Optional
  Chaining](https://blog.webdevsimplified.com/2020-03/javascript-optional-chaining/)

## Second Solution

also if you don't want to use `?.`, you must add some expressions in your condition

```
if (j && j.tagName && j.tagName.toLowerCase() === type) {
        oldTags.push(j);
}
```